# Sequelize randomly throwing error while select

Tags: aws-lambda, sequelize.js, amazon-rds, serverless-framework, sequelize-typescript

I am trying to select categories from the category table. If I execute the select statement several times, let's say 10 times. 3 times will get the exception.

***Exception***

```
Invalid value Where {
  attribute: Fn { fn: 'lower', args: [ Col { col: 'name' } ] },
  comparator: Symbol(like),
  logic: '%%'
  }
```

***Code***

```js
exports.searchProductCategories = (body, username, shopId) => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let searchText = body.searchText.toLowerCase();
        let limit = body.limit;
        let offset = body.offset;
        db.product_category.findAndCountAll({
            where: {
                [Sequelize.Op.or]: [
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col(KEY_NAME_COLUMN)), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col(KEY_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN)), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%')
                ],
                [Sequelize.Op.and]: [
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.col(KEY_SHOP_ID_COLUMN), Sequelize.Op.eq, shopId)
                ]
            },
            order: [
                [Sequelize.fn('lower', Sequelize.col(KEY_NAME_COLUMN)), "ASC"]
            ],
            offset: offset,
            limit: limit,
            attributes: ['id', 'name', 'description'],
        }).then(result => {
            resolve({ [KEY_STATUS]: 1, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "Categories listed successfully", [KEY_DATA]: result.rows, [KEY_TOTAL_COUNT]: result.count });
        }).catch(error => {
            reject({ [KEY_STATUS]: 0, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "Categories list failed", [KEY_ERROR]: error.message });
        });
    })
}
```

It seems perfectly unstable.

I am using Serverless framework in AWS lambda. Database is MySql.

Comment: What do KEY_NAME_COLUMN and KEY_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN equal to?

Comment: @Anatoly Those are column name string constants

Comment: I can guess this because you indicated them in Sequelize.col. I'm interested in clarifying if you indicated the same column names as `name` and in `KEY_NAME_COLUMN` for instance.

Comment: Can you add in the question SQL equivalent of this `where` conditions?

Comment: Select all categories with name or description contains search text. And all the selected should have a specific shop id. This is the explanation. Do you need exact select query? I am surprised because the code is working nearly 70% of the time. @Anatoly

Comment: At least it does not make any sense for me to use `Sequelize.where` and indicate it as a value for `name`, `description` and `shopId` columns. You just need to use `Sequelize.where` directly in the array of Op.or/Op.and conditions. And of course, if you pass the same arguments it can't work differently from time to time (though it might depend on returning data)

Comment: @Anatoly Did you mean, i have to write sql query instead of using sequalize where. Or something else

Comment: I mean something like this `[Sequelize.Op.or]: [
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('LOWER', Sequelize.col(KEY_NAME_COLUMN)), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%'),
                    Sequelize.where(Sequelize.fn('LOWER', Sequelize.col(KEY_DESCRIPTION_COLUMN)), Sequelize.Op.like, '%' + searchText + '%')
                ]`

Comment: @Anatoly I made changes to the codebase based on your suggestion. But still, I am getting the same issue sometimes. But not at all times. I changed the entire question with an error too. Could you please look

Comment: Looks ok. Can you check that all 10 times you pass the same values to Sequelize queries?

Comment: @Anatoly, Yes, with the same values the issue is happening. But I deploy the same to AWS and I did not get it. So there might be some glitch happening by Serverless offline.

Comment: Does it work correctly if you try to run it locally? Could it be an AWS issue?

Comment: @Anatoly I run it locally by the help of Serverless framework offline running `sls start offline`. Is there any other way to run it locally?

Comment: I'm mostly aware of Sequelize here and I don't know how to run AWS-project locally.