# model.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model

Tags: aws-lambda, orm, sequelize.js, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am getting the below error whenever I tried to call any call from serverless framework lambda

```
[offline] _____ HANDLER RESOLVED _____
offline: Failure: product.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
Error: product.hasMany called with something that's not a subclass of Sequelize.Model
    at Function.hasMany (C:\Users\Kiran\Documents\Projects\Rentals-Backend\node_modules\sequelize\lib\associations\mixin.js:18:13)
    at Function.Product.associate (C:\Users\Kiran\Documents\Projects\Rentals-Backend\entity\product.js:21:17)
```

**`IMPORTANT`**

Below code is the answer for the above error. You might missed any steps. So you can refer and fix. Thanks [Anatoly](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1376618/anatoly) who helped me to solve the problem.

**Product model**:

```js
const { STRING, BOOLEAN, INTEGER } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const Product = sequelize.define("product", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        name: { type: STRING },
        description: { type: STRING, allowNull: true },
        purchase_price: { type: STRING },
        tax: { type: STRING },
        sale_price: { type: STRING },
        categoryId: { type: STRING },
        status: { type: BOOLEAN, defaultValue: 0 },
        created_on: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: true },
        updated_on: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: true },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    })
    Product.associate = function (models) {
        Product.hasMany(models.product_image, { as: "images" });
        Product.belongsTo(models.product_category, { as: "category", foreignKey: 'categoryId' });
    };
    return Product;

}
```

**Image model**:

```js
const { STRING, BOOLEAN, INTEGER } = require("sequelize");

module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const ProductImage = sequelize.define("product_image", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        productId: { type: INTEGER },
        fileName: { type: STRING },
        url: { type: STRING },
        position: { type: INTEGER },
        isDefault: { type: BOOLEAN, defaultValue: 0 },
        shopId: { type: STRING },
        status: { type: BOOLEAN, defaultValue: 0 },
        created_on: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: true },
        updated_on: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: true },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    })

    return ProductImage;
}
```

**Category model**:

```js
const { STRING, BOOLEAN, INTEGER } = require("sequelize");


module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
    const ProductCategory = sequelize.define("product_category", {
        id: { type: INTEGER, primaryKey: true, autoIncrement: true },
        name: { type: STRING },
        description: { type: STRING, allowNull: true },
        status: { type: BOOLEAN, defaultValue: 0 },
        created_on: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: true },
        updated_on: { type: INTEGER, allowNull: true },
    }, {
        timestamps: false,
        freezeTableName: true,
    });
    return ProductCategory;
}
```

This is the config file where we initialize sequelize

**Config file**

```js
    const Sequelize = require('sequelize')
    const fs = require('fs')
    const path = require('path')
    const db = {}
    const models = path.join(__dirname, '..', 'entity')
    var basename = path.basename(module.filename)
    
    const sequelize = new Sequelize(
        process.env.DB_NAME,
        process.env.DB_USER,
        process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
        {
            dialect: 'mysql',
            host: process.env.DB_HOST,
            port: process.env.DB_PORT,
            logging: false
        }
    )
    
    fs
      .readdirSync(models)
      .filter(function (file) {
        return (file.indexOf('.') !== 0) && (file !== basename) && (file.slice(-3) === '.js')
      })
      .forEach(function (file) {
        var model = require(path.join(models, file))(
          sequelize,
          Sequelize.DataTypes
        );
        db[model.name] = model;
        
      })
    
    Object.keys(db).forEach(function (modelName) {
      if (db[modelName].associate) {
        db[modelName].associate(db)
      }
    })
    
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize
    db.sequelize = sequelize
    
    module.exports = db
```

Here we are calling product details.

**Calling function**

```js
    const db = require('../config/sequelize-config');
    exports.getProductById = (query, username, shopId) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.product.findOne({
                where: {
                    id: query.id
                },
                attributes: ['id', 'name', 'description', ['purchase_price', 'purchasePrice'], 'tax', ['sale_price', 'salePrice']],
                include: [{
                    model: db.product_image,
                    as: 'images',
                    where: {
                        status: 1
                    },
                    required: false,
                    attributes: ['id', 'fileName', 'position', 'url']
                },
                {
                    model: db.product_category,
                    as: 'category',
                    required: false,
                    attributes: ['id', 'name']
                }]
            }).then(product => {
                if (product) {
                    resolve({ [KEY_STATUS]: 1, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "Product details fetched successfully", [KEY_DATA]: product });
                } else {
                    reject({ [KEY_STATUS]: 0, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "Product details fetch failed" });
                }
            }).catch(error => {
                reject({ [KEY_STATUS]: 0, [KEY_MESSAGE]: "Product details fetch failed", [KEY_ERROR]: error.message });
            });
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid cross-reference errors and similar ones I recommend converting model definitions to functions and registering models and associations in the same one module, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618) and the question

Comment: After trying several hours I am getting `TypeError: Cannot read property 'define' of undefined`

Comment: Can you please update your question above with modified model files and a module with registration where you got this error?

Comment: I added `Config file` and `calling funtion` at the bottom. But the error is getting from `category model` file `let categoryModel = db.sequelize.define("product_category", {` this line.

Comment: You didn't turn your model definitions into functions like it did here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61710568/1376618

Comment: Also, I referred to the documentation again and there will not be mentioned the issue or precaution.

Comment: You're trying to use a module where you register all models in a model module directly and that's not correct at all. That's why you need to define model registration functions and export them from model modules and then call them in a module where you're creating Sequelize instance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239708/discussion-between-kiran-k-j-and-anatoly).

Comment: @Antoly I updated the entire question with the solution given by you. I think we are ver nearer to the solution. Thank you

Comment: You registered `Image` model as `product_image` but you're trying to use in in `hasMany` as `ProductImage`

Comment: Finally I reached the solution. Thank you very much for your great support and guidance.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70036679/sequelize-randomly-throwing-error-while-select?noredirect=1#comment123865725_70036679 For this issue, should I replace all `Sequelize` usage with `db.Sequelize`